# DX7 BATTERY CHECK = 4.3V instead of 3V even after replacing it with new compatible battery

Tags: synthesizer, repair

I bought my Yamanha DX7 with this problem.

The `INTERNAL MEMORY` presets had scrambled named and wouldn't play any sound.

[image: INTERNAL VOICE 7]
[image: INTERNAL VOICE 9]

Reading the different threads on the web, I figured this was due to the battery although the `BATTERY CHECK` showed **4.3V**.

[image: BATTERY CHECK]

Before I attempted to change the battery, I first reloaded the INTERNAL MEMORY with sounds.

## [Loading sounds to Yamaha DX7](http://bobbyblues.recup.ch/sysex_procedure.html#DX7)

Hereafter the steps found on http://bobbyblues.recup.ch

### Set your DX7

1. Button `FUNCTION` then button `8` then set `MIDI CH=1` *i.e. Use the data entry slider or button `YES`/`NO`*
2. Button `8` again then set `SYS INFO AVAIL` with button `YES`
3. Button `INTERNAL MEMORY PROTECT` then set to `OFF` with button `NO`

### Soundbank transfer to your DX7

Used a Macbook Pro + [SysEx Librarian](https://www.snoize.com/SysExLibrarian/)
with a [Cahaya Midi USB Interface 5 Pin Din Plug Cable for PC/Mac](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B0756X668L/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

1. Run your SysEx transfers program on your computer and load or open (depending on the program you are using) the SysEx file you want to transfer
2. Choose "SysEx send" (or the appropriate option) on your SysEx transfers program
3. You must then see `MIDI RECEIVED` on your DX7/TX7 display (transfer is OK)

This operation restored my internal memory, but the next day the presets were gone again and the label were scrambled.

The battery still showing **4.3V**

So I decided to attempt the battery change.

## Battery change

[image: DX7 Opened]

I ordered a [3V - CR2032 solder pin for Yamaha DX7](https://www.ebay.de/itm/CR2032-solder-pin-for-Yamaha-DX7-DX9-DX27-TG99/172989124108?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) found on eBay.

[image: Battery eBay]

I followed the instruction found on the [NEGATRON BLOG](http://www.negatron.org/2009/09/26/installing-a-new-battery-in-a-yamaha-dx7/)

On **my first attempt**, I soldered the battery to 2 wires instead of directly soldering to the board, in order to allow the operation to be easier the next time if needed.

[image: wired battery]

I closed DX7 but I didn't do the `BATTERY CHECK`, so I don't know if showed correct.

I loaded the new presets (using MIDI/USB interface) and all looked fined. I turned ON/OFF the DX7 + un/plugged it and checked the `INTERNAL MEMORY` and the presets were there.

I thought I had resolved it but an hour later the presets were scrambled again. i.e. No sound.

The battery change didn't help. `BATTERY CHECK` showed 4.3V ??? instead of 3V.

I read further and the first comment of the blog page, **Kevin** described my issue. `BATTERY CHECK` showing **4.5V** instead of 3V.

That's when I decided to give my soldering another go. Interestingly **Kevin** says:

> the trace coming off of the positive terminal of the battery that was supposed to connect to the next component had a gap in it in this kind of shape: —||—

I had also noticed that and I had bridged the battery pin to the diode...

On **my second attempt**, I removed the mainboard again and this time, I added more solder to look like on the [picture on the blog](http://www.negatron.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/5_board_bottom_dsc03397.jpg)

Closed the DX7, powered it and `BATTERY CHECK` showed **3V**!!! **YEAH!**

**...BUT** the next day, I switched on my DX7 to my disappointment, the internal memory is corrupt again and to my surprise `BATTERY CHECK` showed **4.3V** ???

## Why would the `BATTERY CHECK` show **3V** after replacement and 4.3V the next day?

Any pointers of what may be happening?

## UPDATE

A minute ago the `BATTERY CHECK` was showing 3V again.
I touched my wires and it fluctuated!

Looks like it might be my soldering or bad wires.

I removed the battery completely `BATTERY CHECK` showed 4.3V!
Wired it again and it's now showing 3V. Let's see if that keeps the memory overnight.

[image: 3V]

Comment: I **highly** suggest you edit out the whole story leading up to your question and just ask your question. We don't need to know the process for loading sounds.

Comment: I will reorganize the question, the history behind the question is important though

Comment: I skipped it and I still understand your question. To me it's just noise. You changed the battery but for some reason it's still not storing the presets correctly. That's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I guess other people will skip the noise too. Thank you Todd.

Comment: What happens if you never turn it off? It's possible there is something besides the battery that is messed up.

Comment: It could be. That is also my 2 cents. I have indeed turned OFF/ON and unplugged from wall socket too (See question) and presets are there for an hour or more. It's not that it's not storing the preset, it's rather that it's not keeping the presets after a period of time (don't know how long). This is actually known issue that you usually resolve by replacing the battery. I may have hit a corner case where something else indeed is happening. The fact that the battery check shows 4.3V instead of 3V is suspicious

Comment: @ToddWilcox I have rewired my battery. may be a bad cable. Voltage fluctuated when I touched the cables. Let's see if that lasts. Thx

Comment: There *may* be a capacitor that helps the battery - they tend not to last as long as the DX7 has been around.

Comment: Today the memory is still intact, but will wait a few days before I confirm. I have heard indeed that some people recap their DX7. Thank you for the other pointer.

Comment: You just need more souls. Everyone knows the DX7 runs on human souls.

Comment: For me it sounds there is a common misconception about the battery: I guess the original part is a rechargable one. So if the battery is worn out or disconnected, we see the voltage applied to charge it: 4.3V. If it is connected, the voltage drops to the battery voltage, which would slowly rise while the unit is powered on (battery charging) and sinks while the unit is switched off (battery used to keep up memory).

Comment: This also explains why old DX7 batteries sometimes look inflated (worn out battery charged to much) and why a replacement usually won't last long (non-rechargable battery gets charged!)

Answer (score 1):

When the battery is not connected, DX7 `BATTERY CHECK` shows **4.3V**

Check that you have wired/soldered properly the new battery, it should show **3V**.

Also this comment in the blog helped a great deal

> the trace coming off of the positive terminal of the battery that was supposed to connect to the next component had a gap in it in this kind of shape: —||—

Another lead is to check/replace the capacitor "that helps the battery" as suggested by @Tim in the comment section